# Определение конфигурации компьютера с помощью с++

Tags: c++

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать такую задачу: определение конфигурации компьютера с помощью C++, определить параметры указанного диска (DOS 32h). Подскажите книгу (сайт), где набраться мудрости?

Answer (score 2):

Вам поможет [Interrupt List от Ralf Brown](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ralf/files.html). Это один из самых основополагающих материалов по данной теме. Единственное, что на английском языке.

Касательно INT 32h - оно отношение к C++ не имеет, хотя и возможно вызвать прерывание вручную (через встроенный ассемблер). Тогда вызов будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
...
__asm
{
  mov ax, 12
  mov bx, 4
  int 0x32
}
...
```

Как вариант - можете использовать что-то в духе вызова `biosdisk` из `<bios.h>`